# SQL exceptions for specific error conditions

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008r2-express

I want to know SQL exception (state) for the

> "Duplicate Error Record"
>   "Null Value"

What are the sql exception (state) for above  ?

Any suggestion

```
 enum FilterMode 
    {
        System_AllData = -1,
        System_Error = -2,
        System_DuplicateError = 3,
        System_NullValues = 2,
    }

    private FilterMode SetFilter(string str) 
    {          
        if (str == "All Record")
            return FilterMode.System_AllData;
        else if (str == "All Error Record")
            return FilterMode.System_Error;
        else if (str == "Duplicate Error Record")
            return FilterMode.System_DuplicateError;
        else if (str == "Null Value")
            return FilterMode.System_NullValues;
        else return FilterMode.System_Error;
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Can you be more clear?  You've tagged this with C#, do you have some code to show us?

Comment: Sorry for offtopic but why do you need these?

Comment: It's all about filtering the Error State .
so can you suggest me what are the SQl state are specified for the above

Comment: The state depends upon where in the engine it gets thrown. A given error message may be possible to have different state numbers. Why do you need to know this? You should use Error Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an [extensive list of error messages here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-1-500.aspx), or you can execute this query to get the ultimate master list of all messages in your SQL Server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.messages
```

Using a suitable `WHERE` clause, I'm sure you can find the ones you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

ErrorCode == 0x80131904 for Duplicate Error Record. I do not know the code for null value